# Combine multiple models(mysql) to template in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, module

I have bootstrap design to bind my django crud like operation. which has Modal to insert data and table to show that data on same page. in insert Modal there is 2, 3 dropdown which i want to populate with my mysql db records . thats why i want to combine two modals in single def.

views.py

```
def deptlist(request):
department = Department.objects.all()
return render(request, 'manageemp.html', {'department': department})


def managemp(request):
employees = Employee.objects.all()
return render(request, "manageemp.html", {'employees': employees})
```

forms.py

```
class EmpForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
     model = Employee
       fields = ["employee_id", "Name", "designation", "department_id", "manager_id", 
        "date_of_joining","date_of_birth", "location_id", "email","contact_number", 
        "password", "created_by", "modified_by", "status", "user_type"]


class dept(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = Department
        fields = ["department_id", "department_name", "created_by", "modified_by", "status"]
```

Comment: Ok so what's stopping you? There's no reason you can't have multiple items in the template context dictionary.

Comment: how can i load this "def deptlist(request):
department = Department.objects.all()
return render(request, 'manageemp.html', {'department': department})

"

Comment: you can return multiple context in a single render `return render(request, "manageemp.html", {'department': department, 'employees': employees})`

Comment: @Linh Nguyen Thanks .. Solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return multiple context within render:

```
def form_view(request):
  department = Department.objects.all()
  employees = Employee.objects.all()
  return render(request, "manageemp.html", {'department': department, 'employees': employees})
```